# Incorrect date range example in search help

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, help-center

Not a bug but documentation glitch. In the searching help page https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching. The example given for date range is incorrect.

It is given as

```
created:2013-04..2012-05
```

which returns nothing and should be

```
created:2012-05..2013-04
```

The lower value of range must precede/must be on the left.

Comment: Or just replace 2012 with 2013. ([`created:2013-04..2013-05`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2013-04..2013-05))

Comment: I think it should be 2012 (i.e. `created:2012-04..2012-05`) to match with the description after it: `between April 1, 2012 and May 31, 2012.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should have been:

```
created:2012-04..2012-05
```

It is, now.