# Search Help: Text for date range for search doesn't match with text for date search query

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, help-center

In the [Search Help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), under the section **Dates**, it says:

> Dates can be entered in the following formats:
>
> - year only – e.g., **created:2012..2013** searches posts created from
>     **January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2012**; [...]

(emphasis mine)

This is similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198370/incorrect-date-range-example-in-search-help), but on a different piece of text in the same section.

As written, it seems to imply that the end range isn't included, that the range stops before it gets to 2013.  I've tested that range; results from 2012 and 2013 are included.

Please correct the text.  Change the text from:

> January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2012

to

> January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in the examples I sent to Laura when made the help article, my fault.  Thanks for the catch, the help text is now updated.

Comment: The dates have been corrected.  Thanks!